# How to change color of column in chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Link codepen: https://codepen.io/01202581905/pen/gOOYzOZ

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'bar',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, -10, 35, 2, -19, 30, 15]
    }]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {}
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

I want to change color of column when value of column as 0 and change position of col . Thank you

Result I want :
[image]

Comment: i done see any yellow bar in ur codepan design and as it is `0` it should not take any place for `0`

Comment: I mean I want 0 to be a bar, not a line, I don't know how to be that

Comment: i dont think its possible what u can do is give minimum number for 0 like 0.5 or something like that

Comment: oh ok . thank you . im try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've solve tour problem:

```
function updateChart(chart){
    let val = 2;
    let updatedValues = [];
    chart.data.datasets[0].data.forEach((e,i)=>{
    if(e===0){
      updatedValues.push('green');
      chart.data.datasets[0].data[i] = val;
      chart.data.datasets.push({data:
        Array.from({length:chart.data.datasets[0].data.length},function(el,j){
            if(i===j) return -val
        })})
    } else {
        updatedValues.push(chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor)
    }

  })
  chart.data.datasets.forEach(e=>{
    e.backgroundColor = updatedValues;
  })

  chart.update()
}
```

And fiddle to testing: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lbjmw6r/

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have to give a array in the backgroundColor-Parameter with in the dataset: see here:

```
var labels = ["001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007"];
var data = [20, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40];
for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i < len; i++) {
   **background_colors**.push(getRandomColor());
}

var barChartData = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)", 
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)", 
    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    backgroundColor: **background_colors**,
    data: data
  }]
};
```

This should work!